# update item with axios on click in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a todo list and I'm trying to update the completed/not-completed boolean on click via axios. I'm not sure how to best approach this.

Unfortunately I'm a total beginner and I lack the general react understanding to find the right approach.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todoList: []
      }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.refreshList();
    }

  refreshList = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/todos/")
      .then(res => this.setState({ todoList: res.data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  handleCheck = () => {
    //toggle the 'completed' property and then update
  };

  update = item => {
      axios
        .put(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${item.id}/`, item)
        .then(res => this.refreshList())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      return;
  };


  renderItems = () => {
    const newItems = this.state.todoList
    return newItems.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <h6>{item.title}</h6>
        <Form>
        <button onClick={this.handleCheck(item)} type="submit" ></button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <h4>ToDos</h4>
      {this.renderItems()}
    );
  }
}
```

todo data-structure:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Todo #1",
   "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
   "completed": false
  }
```

EDIT:

Update: I managed to successfully update the "completed" boolean with the commented line, updating the value directly. But I understand that is the non-ideal way, but when trying to do the same through setState I get a Unexpected Token Error, "Unexpected token, expected , (39:27)". How can I edit setState to function properly?

```
  handleCheck = (item, index) => {

    this.setState({todoList[index].completed : !todoList[index].completed});
    // this.state.todoList[index].completed = !this.state.todoList[index].completed;
    this.update(item);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the index of your todo to `handleCheck` function and toggle the completed value.

```
handleCheck = (item, index) => {
  //whatever needs to happen here to updated the 'completed' property
  this.setState({
    todoList: [...this.state.todoList.slice(0, index),
    Object.assign({}, this.state.todoList[index], {completed: !this.state.todoList[index].completed}),
    ...this.state.todoList.slice(index + 1)
    ]
  });

  this.update(item);
};

renderItems = () => {
  const newItems = this.state.todoList || [];
  return newItems.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <h6>{item.title}</h6>
      <Form>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleCheck(item, index)} type="submit" ></button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  ));
};
```

**Simplified version,** create a copy of your todoList and update todo using the index.

```
handleCheck = (item, index) => {

  const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.todoList));

  copy[index].completed = !copy[index].completed;

  this.setState({
    todoList: copy
  });

  this.update(item);
};
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      todoList: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Todo #1",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "completed": false
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Todo #2",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "completed": false
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Todo #3",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "completed": false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleCheck = (item, index) => {

    const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.todoList));

    copy[index].completed = !copy[index].completed;

    this.setState({
      todoList: copy
    });

    // this.update(item);
  };

  renderItems = () => {
    const newItems = this.state.todoList || [];
    return newItems.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <h6>
        {item.completed ? <strike>{item.title}</strike> : item.title}</h6>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleCheck(item, index)} >Submit</button>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       
        <p>
          Todos
        </p>
        {this.renderItems()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Comment: This works. Please mention that it is not suggested to do such updations in front end rather do it on the server.

Comment: what's wrong with updating the items from the client side?

Comment: Doing it client side is okay if you are making a web app for fun. So it is better to let them know that for a real project doing client-side updates and then sending data is less secure

Comment: Thank you so much for answers, I understood a bit more about react now.  I just have one little follow up question: I think I found a somewhat simpler solution, but for some reason it gives me a Unexpected Token Error when trying to setState, but oddly setting the value directly works (the commented line beneath setState). How can I edit setState to work?  *see Edit

Comment: don't do this `this.setState({todoList[index].completed : !todoList[index].completed});`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called that update function anywhere, while you've called that handle click function on button's click.

So, simply take items as a parameter in handle check function and call the update function from there, it'll work

```
handleCheck = (item) => {
  this.update(item)
}
```

Comment: hi omer, thanks for your suggestion. But I still need to toggle the "completed"  boolean before updating, that's where I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todoList: []
      }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.refreshList();
    }

  refreshList = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/todos/")
      .then(res => this.setState({ todoList: res.data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  handleCheck = (item) => {
       this.update(item)
       // Make your backend do the update
  };

  update = item => {
      axios
        .put(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${item.id}/`, item)
        .then(res => this.refreshList())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      return;
  };


  renderItems = () => {
    const newItems = this.state.todoList
    return newItems.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <h6>{item.title}</h6>
        <Form>
       // See this line ( how to bind functions )
        <button onClick={this.handleCheck.bind(this, item)} type="submit" ></button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <h4>ToDos</h4>
      {this.renderItems()}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Prajval, thanks for your comment and suggestion, just one question. If I send the put request right away without toggling the "completed" value the update would remain the same, with unchanged data.  What would be ideal way of toggling the boolean value of "completed" before sending the put request? I understand from your comment on the other solution that updating state is unsafe in production. But I will have to toggle the value in some way before submitting the put request, not?

Comment: put request is just a type of request. It has nothing to do with what your data must do. Your server will have a put request handler which will use the data and update the DB where ur todos are stored. You can also do this with POST or GET request. A POST request is always preferable when you have some data to deal with. PUT is useful for file uploads and stuff. GET for getting information. But all of them can (except GET) can be interchanged

Answer (score 0):

This solution was suggested by Junius L. but I had to alter/simplify the handleCheck function. So here is the altered solution and my learnings, maybe this helps someone. Also please comment in case my conclusions are incorrect.

Learning #1: Do not update state without using setState()
Learning #2: You cannot update a property at the second level of state. Instead, copy state it into a local variable, make the needed updates and then set the entire state new.

```
handleCheck = (item, index) => {

    const items = this.state.todoList
    items[index].completed = !items[index].completed
    this.setState({todoList:items});
    this.update(item);

  };

renderItems = () => {
  const newItems = this.state.todoList || [];
  return newItems.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <h6>{item.title}</h6>
      <Form>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleCheck(item, index)} type="submit" ></button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  ));
};
```